# display html format text to dynamic textfield in as3 work in loacal , but online don't display text

Tags: html, actionscript-3, text, textfield

found that code to display html format text to dynamic textfield in as3:

```
var url:String = "http://edeejay.dyndns.org:8000/currentsong?sid=1";
var loadit:URLLoader = new URLLoader();     
loadit.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
loadit.load(new URLRequest(url));    
function completeHandler(event:Event):void {    
     myText_txt.htmlText = event.target.data as String;
}
```

all work fine in local , but when upload to the net , swf can’t display the text ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more likely a [cross-domain](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html) problem.

Listen to `SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR` and `IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR` to confirm that. And in general you should always listen to them to know if something wrong happens.

Comment: should i put crossdomain.xml in http://edeejay.dyndns.org:8000/
that is shoutcast server .....?????

Comment: Do you get the security error? If yes, then you have to put a crossdomain in your server. Where is the swf hosted, on the domain edeejay.dyndns.org:8000?

Comment: no hosted in electronic-deejay.com ( web site radio ) 
excatly here http://electronic-deejay.com/live/ 
player for radio , you ca see it ,want to display title song

Comment: So yes, I think you have to put a cross domain in edeejay.dyndns.org:8000 so that it allows the swf (that is located on another domain) to load data.